# Using MS Excel VSTO Add-In How to Suppress Standard Excel 'Save As' Function and Show Custom Window for saving?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ms-office, office-addins

I'm creating an Excel VSTO Add-In.

I want to Suppress the standard 'Save As' and Open Custom Window when 'Save As' is pressed.

I've been able to show Custom Save Dialog on Save (i.e. Ctrl + S) action. Through this Window I'm able to save the documents directly on the cloud instead of saving it locally.

In the same way, I want to suppress standard 'Save As' and Open a custom Window.

Following's the code I'm using for Save i.e. 'Ctrl + S'

```
private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Application.WorkbookBeforeSave += Application_WorkbookBeforeSave;
    } 


private void Application_WorkbookBeforeSave(Excel.Workbook Wb, bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
    {
     
        Cancel = true;
        SaveAsUI = false;
        
        Save saveDialog = new Save()
            {
                ChangeCaption = SetWindowCaption
            };
            saveDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to repurpose the corresponding ribbon controls, see [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Also, you may want to set a keyboard hook, see [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw).

Comment: Thanks Eugene! I'll try to implement it, I'll update you on this shortly.